Is it possbile that i can get this outcome?
i am trying to get the result as attached.
however i need the where clause for user to select their own date in power bi.
whenever i try to add date in where clause, i cant display the result as expected.
may i know do anyone have tips/clue on this?
many thanks


TABLE 1
<table border='1'>
<tr><TD>TEAM</TD></tr>
<tr><TD>A</TD></tr>
<tr><TD>B</TD></tr>
<tr><TD>C</TD></tr>
<tr><TD>D</TD></tr>
<tr><TD>E</TD></tr>
</table>

<BR><BR>
TABLE 2
<table border='1'>
<tr>
  <TD>TEAM</TD>
  <TD>DATEE</TD>
  <TD>PRICE</TD>
 </tr>
<tr>
  <TD>A</TD>
  <TD>2406</TD>
  <TD>10</TD>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <TD>B</TD>
  <TD>2406</TD>
  <TD>20</TD>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <TD>C</TD>
  <TD>2407</TD>
  <TD>30</TD>
 </tr>

</table>

<BR><BR>
EXPECTED RESULT
<table border='1'>
<tr>
  <TD>TEAM</TD>
  <TD>DATEE</TD>
  <TD>PRICE</TD>
 </tr>
<tr>
  <TD>A</TD>
  <TD>2406</TD>
  <TD>10</TD>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <TD>B</TD>
  <TD>2406</TD>
  <TD>20</TD>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <TD>C</TD>
  <TD>(null)</TD>
  <TD>(null)</TD>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <TD>D</TD>
  <TD>(null)</TD>
  <TD>(null)</TD>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <TD>E</TD>
   <TD>(null)</TD>
  <TD>(null)</TD>
 </tr>

</table>



SELECT
table1.team,
table2.datee,
table2.price
from
table1 left join table2 on table1.team=table2.team
and table2.datee='2406'
--where table2.datee='2406' --need this for users to input but will not display the result as expected


In what way does your actual output differ from the expected output?

Hi @MaxAlexander, thanks for ur reply! currently i can only hardcoded 2406 after the join, however the user need to select the date that they prefer in the reporting tools. For example, if the user select 2047, it will be exactly same as 'where table2.datee=2407 and that will not display all the teams in table 1.

The user's input must go into the where clause? You cannot put it into the join?

Please don’t link to images. Add all relevant information to your question as editable text, appropriately formatted

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@NickW, i had removed the images and changed into tables. thanks!

by the way, you can create nice tables using markdown - no need for html

Putting the user's input parameter into the join at "table2.datee=[@param]" should solve the problem. If, for some reason, this is not an option, you can achieve the same result via a where clause by using a temporary table:
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (
  SELECT *
  FROM Table2 t2
  WHERE t2.DATEE = 2406
);

SELECT t1.TEAM, t2.DATEE, t2.PRICE
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN tmp t2 ON t1.Team = t2.Team;

